# Why my buttons for the Icarousel view was stuck?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, icarousel

I've iCarousel view in my project which contains list of images, I've designed two buttons, one for skip to next and another is for skip to previous of the images, when I click these buttons continuously these buttons are stuck, how to rectify this issue?

Comment: how about some code for the button presses?

Comment: What about the memory? 
Maybe you do not clean up.

Comment: [carouselobject scrollToItemAtIndex:carouselobject.currentItemIndex + 1 duration :0.5];

Comment: You have a bug on line 173 of your code.

Comment: The button actions are:[carouselobject scrollToItemAtIndex:carouselobject.currentItemIndex + 1 duration :0.5];  [carouselobject scrollToItemAtIndex:carouselobject.currentItemIndex - 1 duration :0.5];

Comment: How in the world is anybody supposed to help you with such a vague question? You need to add breakpoints to the actions on your buttons and make sure the action methods are being called. Then, step through the code for the actions in the debugger. If you still can't figure out what's going wrong, post the code for your IBAction methods, as well as what you found in the debugger when you tried to step through the code. Do you have an outlet to your carousel? Is it non-nil? What is the value of currentItemIndex for the carousel?

Comment: What you mean by line 173? make it clear?Already checked my code using  break points in the buttons Actions